# Efficient Algorithm For Projection Onto A Convex Set

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Given $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $\tau$ a scalar, I would like to solve the following Euclidean projection problem:

$\underset{p}{\mathrm{argmin}} \; \|\mathbf{p}-\mathbf{x}\|_2
\;\;
\mathrm{s.t.}
\;\;
\displaystyle \sum_{i}{
\left \| \left [
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{f}_i^\mathrm{T} \\
\mathbf{g}_i^\mathrm{T}
\end{array}
\right] \cdot \mathbf{p} \right \|_2 }
\leq \tau
$,

where $\mathbf{f}_i,\mathbf{g}_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

The above is a convex function over a convex set and as such should have a unique solution. Moreover, we can find the upper bound on the summation as follows:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i}{
\left \| \left [
\begin{array}{c}
\mathbf{f}_i^\mathrm{T} \\
\mathbf{g}_i^\mathrm{T}
\end{array}
\right] \cdot \mathbf{p} \right \|_2 }
\leq
\|\mathbf{p}\|_2 \cdot \sum_i \sigma_i
$,

where $\sigma_i$ is the operator norm of the $2 \times n$ matrix $[\mathbf{f}_i \;\; \mathbf{g}_i]^{\mathrm{T}}$.

I have been using CVX to solve the above, but it's just too slow in its current form. I have not figured out how to make use of them, but the operator norms are easily found before-hand. Can anyone suggest a re-formulation of the above or an algorithm that is tailored to these types of problems?

Comment: Can't you use Lagrange multiplier method and solve?

Comment: @Ashok: I have to admit that I do not see how to do that.

Comment: Would your problem be OK with small change of the constraint? Instead of using the norm $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{2} $ could you use the squared norm $ {\left\| \cdot \right\|}_{2}^{2} $?